# What is difference between versions of eclipse like juno, kepler etc.? Which version to choose for web development?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, web-deployment

Eclipse has so many versions like Juno, Indigo, Galileo, etc.

Are they just versions or they are specific for what we are developing? If they are specific which one to choose for web development?

Currently I have Juno which I am using for android development, is it possible to use same eclipse for web development by adding plugins? If yes please provide the link to download the plugin and also help me with its configuration in ubuntu.

Comment: Java EE for developers. Anyway, you can boost your eclipse version with plugins. My eclipse takes 1Gb on plugins. I can do almost everithing except sending mail and IM

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113206/eclipse-juno-vs-eclipse-kepler/23193201#23193201

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juno, indigo, Galileo are friendly names for release versions of Eclipse platform:

- Galileo is 3.5
- Indigo is 3.7
- Juno is 4.2
- Luna is 4.4

Eclipse providers "prepackaged" distributions for your specific needs - http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/. For example http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/lunasr2 is for PHP developers.

I am not sure what specific web development you are interested in, but you can use [WTP](https://eclipse.org/webtools/) (Web Tools Platform) [update site](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/juno/) to install what WTP offers. You use [Eclipse Update Manager](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-34.htm) to do that.

Starting with Eclipse 3.7 I believe there is [Eclipse Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/) installation method (Help -> Eclipse Marketplace) which makes it even easier to find what you are looking for.

You can also use [Eclipse Project Search](http://projects.eclipse.org/search/projects) to find specific project you are interested in and use its update site to install in into Eclipse.

Note that latest update site for the projects might not work with your distribution. For example, if you are trying to install something that is made for Eclipse 4.4 into Eclipse 3.5. However, you can try downloading latest Eclipse - Luna, and point to your existing workspace and it should work fine.

Comment: `However, you can try downloading latest Eclipse - Luna, and point to your existing workspace and it should work fine.`. Not always. These things are like printers.They aways break when you don't have enough time to fix them up

Answer (score 0):

Different eclipse packages exist for different development needs, so for java development you would download the eclipse sdk for java development and for web, you would need the Eclipse Java EE package.

It is possible to install plugins into your existing eclipse and use it for Web application development as well. For this, you will need the wtp plugins which can be installed from the eclipse project update site. Just choose install new software from the help menu.