# Differences inbetween Eclipse Versions

Tags: eclipse, version

I´m asking myself if there is any possibility to compare different versions of Eclipse. I googled a little but I couldn´t find any "easy-to-view"-site that could´ve helped me.

In my case I´m looking for the differences between Eclipse 3.7 and 4.5 (the latest) and I´m interested in almost everything that has changed. 
(Or would it just be enough to compare the projects?)

Cheers, Elias

Comment: Have you looked at the release notes? They are not easy-to-view but..

Comment: Well, Yes, but they should just show me the differences between an versions release notes and it´s previous version. Right?

Comment: Yes. and AFAIK, you have to read all the changelogs for all versions from 3.7 to 4.5

Comment: Okay, thanks! I just hoped to not have this work =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct solution to this. But you can compare 3.5 vs 3.6, 3.6 vs 3.7 etc.

Read news and noteworthy section of each eclipse release to identify the main difference.

Refer this post [Eclipse Juno vs Eclipse Kepler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113206/eclipse-juno-vs-eclipse-kepler/23193201#23193201) for how to compare two eclipse versions and the change log between two in details.